# Routing to a page without it displaying in router outlet? Angular2

Tags: angular2-routing

In my app.component.html I have, lets say

```
<header></header>
<sidebar></sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When I click on a link, the page displays in router outlet, but is it possible to have one page that displays full width(no header, no sidebar)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "routerLink" mate:

[enter link description here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)